# C++ WinApp Scroll bar undeclared global variables.

Tags: c++

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx( 
    0,                     // no extended styles 
    g_szWindowClass,       // global string containing name of window class
    g_szTitle,             // global string containing title bar text 
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |  
        WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL, // window styles 
    CW_USEDEFAULT,         // default horizontal position 
    CW_USEDEFAULT,         // default vertical position 
    CW_USEDEFAULT,         // default width 
    CW_USEDEFAULT,         // default height 
    (HWND) NULL,           // no parent for overlapped windows 
    (HMENU) NULL,          // use the window class menu 
    g_hInst,               // global instance handle  
    (PVOID) NULL           // pointer not needed 
);
```

I copied and pasted directly from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But, however the variables starting with 'g_' are undefined, how do I define them? I am not finding that info on Microsoft site.

Oh and My Goal is too create a scroll bar. (vertical)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g_ indicates a global variable; Declare the 3 variables with a prefix of _g as global. Set

```
wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"WindowClassName";  

g_szTitle = L"Name"; // use this 

g_hInst = thisInstance; // one of mains parameters
```

So something like this:
    // This is unicode.

```
wchar_t szClassName[] = L"ClassRegisterName";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nFunsterStil) {
...

hwnd = CreateWindow(szClassName, L"Your Title", WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
100, 50, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, hThisInstance, NULL);
```